# Pollinating dragon fruit in broad daylight

Tags: cactus, pollination

Most tutorials on pollinating dragon fruit say that the flower will open past midnight. They suggest to go out with a flashlight and use a paintbrush to pollinate it.

If I don’t want to screw up my sleep schedule, can I do this in broad daylight? I currently see a flower but it is not open. I can just use my hand to manually open it. Will doing this harm the flower or just plainly fail at generating a fruit?

[image]